# questions about AES irreducible polynomials

Tags: encryption, aes, galois-field

For galois field GF(2^8), the polynomial's format is a7x^7+a6x^6+...+a0.

For AES, the irreducible polynomial is x^8+x^4+x^3+x+1.

Apparently, the max power in GF(2^8) is x^7, but why the max power of irreducible polynomial is x^8?

How will the max power in irreducible polynomial affect inverse result in GF?

Can I set the max power of irreducible polynomial be x^9?

Comment: This is not a programming question or issue; it is about the mathematics used in a cryptographic algorithm and would be on-topic on cryptography.stackexchange.com math.stackexchange.com or mathoverflow.net although I wouldn't be surprised if it's already answered in at least one of them

Comment: From [non-prime fields](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_field#Non-prime_fields): *Given a prime power q = p\*\*n with p prime and n > 1, the field GF(q) may be explicitly constructed in the following way. One first chooses an irreducible polynomial P in GF(p)[X] of degree n ...*. So the irreducible used to define GF(256) must be of degree 8, not 7.

Answer (score 3):

To understand why the modulus of GF(2⁸) must be order 8 (that is, have 8 as its largest exponent), you must know how to perform polynomial division with coefficients in GF(2), which means you must know how to perform polynomial division in general. I will assume you know how to do those things. If you don't know how, there are many tutorials on the web from which you can learn.

Remember that if `r = a mod m`, it means that there is a `q` such that `a = q m + r`. To make a working GF(2⁸) arithmetic, we need to guarantee that `r` is a element of GF(2⁸) for any `a` and `q` (even though `a` and `q` do **not** need to be elements of GF(2⁸)). Furthermore, we need to ensure that `r` can be **any** element of GF(2⁸), if we pick the right `a` from GF(2⁸).

So we must pick a modulus (the `m`) that makes these guarantees. We do this by picking an `m` of exactly order 8.

If the numerator of the division (the `a` in `a = q m + r`) is order 8 or higher, we can find something to put in the quotient (the `q`) that, when multiplied by x⁸, cancels out that higher order. But there's nothing we can put in the quotient that can be multiplied by x⁸ to give a term with order **less** than 8, so the remainder (the `r`) can be any order up to and including 7.

Let's try a few examples of polynomial division with a modulus (or divisor) of x⁸+x⁴+x³+x+1 to see what I mean. First let's compute x⁸+1 mod x⁸+x⁴+x³+x+1:

```
                1            <- quotient
             ┌──────────────
x⁸+x⁴+x³+x+1 │ x⁸        +1
             -(x⁸+x⁴+x³+x+1)
             ───────────────
                  x⁴+x³+x    <- remainder
```

So x⁸+1 mod x⁸+x⁴+x³+x+1 = x⁴+x³+x.

Next let's compute x¹²+x⁹+x⁷+x⁵+x² mod x⁸+x⁴+x³+x+1.

```
               x⁴ +x +1                      <- quotient
             ┌──────────────────────────────
x⁸+x⁴+x³+x+1 │ x¹²+x⁹   +x⁷+x⁵      +x²
             -(x¹²   +x⁸+x⁷+x⁵+x⁴      )
             ───────────────────────────
                   x⁹+x⁸      +x⁴   +x²
                 -(x⁹      +x⁵+x⁴   +x²+x)
                 ─────────────────────────
                      x⁸   +x⁵         +x
                    -(x⁸      +x⁴+x³   +x+1)
                    ────────────────────────
                            x⁵+x⁴+x³     +1  <- remainder
```

So x¹²+x⁹+x⁷+x⁵+x² mod x⁸+x⁴+x³+x+1 = x⁵+x⁴+x³+1, which has order < 8.

Finally, let's try a substantially higher order: how about x¹⁰⁰+x⁹⁶⁺x⁹⁵+x⁹³+x⁸⁸+x⁸⁷+x⁸⁵+x⁸⁴+x mod x⁸+x⁴+x³+x+1?

```
               x⁹²             +x⁸⁴                    <- quotient
             ┌────────────────────────────────────────
x⁸+x⁴+x³+x+1 │ x¹⁰⁰+x⁹⁶⁺x⁹⁵+x⁹³    +x⁸⁸+x⁸⁷+x⁸⁵+x⁸⁴+x
             -(x¹⁰⁰+x⁹⁶+x⁹⁵+x⁹³+x⁹²                  )
             ─────────────────────────────────────────
                                x⁹²+x⁸⁸+x⁸⁷+x⁸⁵+x⁸⁴+x
                              -(x⁹²+x⁸⁸+x⁸⁷+x⁸⁵+x⁸⁴  )
                              ────────────────────────
                                                    x  <- remainder
```

So x¹⁰⁰+x⁹⁶⁺x⁹⁵+x⁹³+x⁸⁸+x⁸⁷+x⁸⁵+x⁸⁴+x mod x⁸+x⁴+x³+x+1 = x. Note that I carefully chose the numerator so that it wouldn't be a long computation. If you want some pain, try doing x¹⁰⁰ mod x⁸+x⁴+x³+x+1 by hand.